# How create 2 row chart with 2 subgroups

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have this dataset

```
var arr = [{col1:"group1",col2:"subgroup1_1",amount:10},
            {col1:"group1",col2:"subgroup1_2",amount:30},
            {col1:"group1",col2:"subgroup1_1",amount:80},
            {col1:"group1",col2:"subgroup1_2",amount:10},
            {col1:"group2",col2:"subgroup2_1",amount:20},
            {col1:"group2",col2:"subgroup2_1",amount:40},
            {col1:"group2",col2:"subgroup2_2",amount:20},
            {col1:"group2",col2:"subgroup2_2",amount:90}];
```

I need create two row charts:

- first row chart  with subgroup1_1 and subgroup1_2, uincluded in group1;
- second row chart with subgroup2_1 and subgroup2_2, uincluded in group2.

Please help, code is attached - https://jsfiddle.net/spectr747/827s3m59/25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into dc.js or crossfilter to split a group the way you have described.

But it's pretty easy to construct a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) that will filter the bins returned by the group, and only show the ones that match a prefix.

#### filtering by key

Here is a constructor function for a fake group that filters bins by key:

```
function filter_keys(source_group, f) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return f(d.key);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Use it like this:

```
rowChart_2
  // ...
  .group(filter_keys(bGroup, k => /^subgroup1/.test(k)));

rowChart_3
  // ...
  .group(filter_keys(bGroup, k => /^subgroup2/.test(k)));
```

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0ckrtof2/11/).

Note that the two row charts won't filter each other because [a group does not observe its own dimension's groups](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters). You could use two dimensions with the same definition if you want them to filter each other (but one will completely drop to zero when the other is filtered).

#### filtering by another field

After I wrote the above answer, I noticed that you want to split by another field, not by matching the key string.

It's a little more complicated, but you can create a composite key for your dimension:

```
bDim = ndx.dimension(function (d){ return [d.col1, d.col2]; });
```

The first array element of the key is the column we want to split by, and the second is the key we want to display.

Then construct a fake group which filters by the first key and removes it:

```
function filter_by_key_part(source_group, k) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all()
              .filter(({key: [k1, k2]}) => k1 === k)
              .map(({key: [k1, k2], value}) => ({key: k2, value}))
        }
    };
}
```

Use it like this:

```
rowChart_2
  // ...
  .group(filter_by_key_part(bGroup, 'group1'))
```

[New version of fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0ckrtof2/16/).